# PHP (Change the pageid to the page name.)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am making the dynamic website in PHP. While code is running good using pageid.

The url is now like `www.google.com/pageid=1`

Now, i want to change the url for 1 level pages as `www.google.com/page1`

- for level 2 as www.google.com/page1/page2
- for level 3 as www.google.com/page1/page2/page3

While unique address is stored in the my table as page1,page2,page3.

How can it be possible to change url at run time. Please give the examples and comments. So that it may helpful to understand.

Also i want to know if it is possible using the .htaccess file. If possible How .htaccess `%{REQUESTED_FILE}%` will reach out for my unique url's that are stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

$URL= "www.google.com/page1"

1) split the string with '/'

```
 $data =   explode("/",$URL);
 $data[1] will have page1 value
```

2) replace the string `page` with ""

```
 $pageId = str_replace("page","", $data[1]);
```

3) whatever is left is the page id

`pageId` has the value now.

Use that to query the database.

Another way is to use regex to extract the number from page1 and use it where-ever you want to use it.

Comment: Suppose i have the url like this http://www.google.com/page_id=2. In database its unique url is stored as page. Now i want to show the name in place of page_id=2 e.g. the new url will look like this http://www.google.com/page. It is the url. How it can be possible to change the url from page_id to its unique name that is stored in the database table.

Comment: Please give me the solutions. How can i implement this in PHP.